# Save/update data in one form with php and jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, forms

I have an html form with three input text fields

ID:

First Name:

Last Name:

and a submit button for saving data to MySQL, when a user enter the first and last name and click on submit it will create a new record in the table and return the id in the ID filed,
for update the user will enter an id in the ID filed and using jquery I will retrieve the details in the first & last name,

My question is, after the user enter the id in the ID filed is there any way to save the value of ID in a hidden filed or session, or any thing can inform me that the form in update status for Id number xxxx ?

Comment: can you provide some jsfiddle ? it may turn that cookie is ok for you

Comment: I think you answered your own question. You can do it with sessions.  `$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id']` should work

Answer (score 0):

you can save data in variable or in element itself

to demostrate this:
http://jsfiddle.net/VUJ83/1/

HTML:

```
<input class="watchme" name="test" type=text \> 
<input class="watchme" name="test1" type=text value="changeme"\>
<input class="watchme" name="test2" type=text \>

<button id="show">Show changed</button>
<div id="messages"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
input {
 display: block;   
}
.watchme.changed {
background: red;    
}
```

JS:

```
$('.watchme').on('keydown', function(e) {
if ($(this).data().savedval === undefined) {
        $(this).data().savedval = $(this).val();
    }
});
$('.watchme').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('changed');
    if ($(this).val() === $(this).data().savedval) {
        $(this).removeClass('changed');
    }
});

$('#show').click(function() {
    var msgs = $('#messages')
    msgs.html('');
    $('.watchme.changed').each(function() {
        msgs.append($('<div>').html($(this).attr('name')));
    });

});​
​
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery/ajax for the save update then you should try this

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
url: "myfile.php",
type: "POST",
data: {firstname : $('#firstname').val(), lastname: $('#lastname').val() },//you can also pass extra field to identify save or update
success: function(res){
 $('#hiddenField').val(res);
}
});
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
//your query here 
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
echo $id;
?>
```